# WPF - DataGrid only showing the properties of the baseclass

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am trying to fill a DataGrid with a `List<>` of multiple objects. These objects all inherent from a baseclass. I am successful in showing the columns and rows in the DataGrid, however I only see the properties of the base class and not the properties of the child class.

Unfortunately I could not find much helpful information while searching the web. But I am still new to WPF and C# so maybe that's the problem...

How can I get the DataGrid to show all of the properties, from both the base and child class?

EDIT:
I have a few classes(say A, B, C) that inherit from the BaseClass and I have a list of the type `List<BaseClass>` which house multiple objects of multiple types. I need to show all the different child classes in my DataGrid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Prop1}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Prop2}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

```
class Base
{
}

class Derived1: Base
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
}

class Derived2: Base
{
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}

private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.DataContext = new List<Base>()
    {
        new Derived1(){Prop1 = "Hello"},
        new Derived2() {Prop2 = "World"}
    };
}
```

This works for me. I see Hello in first row and World in second.

Comment: Yes, this works quite well. Only problem I now have is that I have empty columns. Is there a property in the DataGrid to auto hide empty columns? I and a co-student looked for one but couldn't find it.

Comment: Set MinWidth="0" Width="Auto" on DataGridColumns

Answer (score 0):

What is the `T` in your `List<T>` ? The type metadata is inferred from that (in winforms binding, at least; so I assume this applies to WPF too). So if you have a `List<BaseClass>` then only the properties of `BaseClass` will be shown. Try using a `List<DerivedClass>` instead.

Comment: What if I need to show the properties of multiple DerivedClass's and the BaseClass?

Comment: a `List<DerivedClass>` should show everything in the object hierarchy up to `DerivedClass`, but most grids can only display homogeneous data - it will only work if there is some commonality between the objects. So if you mean that you have an `A : BaseClass` and a `B : BaseClass`, then you can't show the `A` properties and `B` properties at the same time. You can display the *shared* properties, or you can create a list of just the `A` objects or just the `B` objects (in a `List<A>` or `List<B>` respectively).

Comment: However, if you have `C : BaseClass` and `A : C` and `B : C`, then a `List<C>` will show everything from `BaseClass` and `C`

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `List<ChildClass>` instead of a `List<BaseClass>`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can bind your DataGridColumn which belongs to child classes.

object name of child class.property name of corresponding child class